# ¿Como hago que se repita la pregunta si el usuario ingresa un dato incorrecto?

Tags: python, python-3.x

quiero hacer un contador de puntajes para un juego de cartas, el problema es que hay dos rondas opcionales que se pueden jugar, por lo que le pregunto al usuario si quiere jugarlas. Esto lo hago mediante un **input()**. Logro hacer el programa funcionar si es que el usuario ingresa el texto que le solicito (Si/No), pero no logro que el usuario pueda volver a responder la pregunta si es que ingresa una respuesta que no le solicito.

```
opcion = input("¿Quieres jugar la ronda opcional?(Si/No): ").lower()

while opcion != "si" or "no":
    print("Opción no disponible, intentalo denuevo.")
    opcion = input("¿Quieres jugar la ronda opcional?(Si/No)").lower()

if opcion == "si":
    print("Jugarás la ronda opcional.")

elif opcion == "no":
    print("No jugarás la ronda opcional.")
```

Quiero lograr que el usuario deba repetir la pregunta hasta que escriba "si" o "no", pero el codigo no me da resultados. No sale ningún mensaje de error, solo no cumple mi objetivo.

También intenté reemplazar el `while opcion != "si" or "no"` con `while not opcion == "si" or "no"` pero no obtuve resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La evaluación tienes que hacerla con cada opción, una para "si" y otra para "no" y en lugar de usar `or` debes usar `and`,  así:

`opcion != "si" and opcion != "no":`

El código quedaría algo así:

```
opcion = input("¿Quieres jugar la ronda opcional?(Si/No): ").lower()

while opcion != "si" and opcion != "no":
    print("Opción no disponible, intentalo de nuevo.")
    opcion = input("¿Quieres jugar la ronda opcional? (Si/No)").lower()

    if opcion == "si":
      print("Jugarás la ronda opcional.")
    elif opcion == "no":
      print("No jugarás la ronda opcional.")
```

La siguiente imagen es de una prueba que hice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Similar a la respuesta de @danielperezv, solo agregar una identación a la condición, para que se imprima el mensaje si la opción es válida desde la primera vez.

```py
opcion = input("¿Quieres jugar la ronda opcional?(Si/No): ").lower()

while opcion != "si" and opcion != "no":
    print("Opción no disponible, intentalo de nuevo.")
    opcion = input("¿Quieres jugar la ronda opcional? (Si/No)").lower()

if opcion == "si":
  print("Jugarás la ronda opcional.")
elif opcion == "no":
  print("No jugarás la ronda opcional.")
```